# "Exemplary spaces" for the class of spaces satisfying separation axioms

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms

The Sierpiński space, $S=\{0,1\}$ with the topology $\{ \{\}, \, \{1\}, \, \{0,1\}\}$, is a $T_{0}$ space. And in some sense, it is the "prototypical" $T_{0}$ space, for, if $(X,\tau)$ is a topological space, $X$ is $T_{0}$ iff $X$ can be seen as a subspace of $\prod _{A \in \tau} S$. To be accurate, $X$ is $T_{0}$ if, and only if,
$$
X \hookrightarrow \prod _{A \in \tau} S  \; | \;
x \mapsto (\mathbb{I} _{A}(x))_{A \in \tau}
$$
(I mean, the arrow is injective, and the topology on $X$ is the same as the initial topology with respect to this arrow.)

Are there similar characterizations of other kinds of spaces? Are there similar exemplary $T_{q}$ spaces for other $q$?

Comment: You might consider the cofinite topology to be the "exemplary" $T_1$ space, in the sense that a $T_1$ space is a space whose topology is a (not necessarily proper) refinement of the cofinite topology. (To be more precise, of course, there's not just one "cofinite topology space"... there's one for every cardinality.) This isn't analogous to the example you gave, though, so I'm not sure if this is the kind of answer you're looking for.

Comment: @echinodermata Thanks. What I had in mind was "encoding" the features of, in this case, $T_{1}$ spaces, in concrete objects of this kind, and fairly general arrows: in the example of $T_{0}$ spaces, this arrow is described by the characteristic functions of open sets (though this sets depend, obviously, on the specific space). If one is able to consider a "refinement function", then one can do something of this sort -I guess- by asigning, a space, its cardinality, the corresponding cofinite topology and a way to retrive the original topology...

Comment: I think the only other one is completely regular + $T_1$ (so $T_{3\frac{1}{2}}$, in usual parlance), where either $[0,1]$ or $\mathbb{R}$ would work (we can embed completely regular spaces into powers of the reals or Tychonoff cubes). I seem to recall no such space can exist for $T_1$, $T_2$ or $T_3$, but I cannot recall a reference...

Comment: What you have essentially noticed here is that the power $S^\kappa$ is [_universal_](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/UniversalSpace.html) for the class of T$_0$-spaces of [weight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base_(topology)#Weight_and_character) $\leq \kappa$ (where $\kappa$ is an infinite cardinal).

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, $[0,1]$ is an "exemplary" completely regular space; this is essentially the definition of "completely regular".  On the other hand, there is no exemplary $T_1$ or $T_2$ space.

For $T_1$ spaces, let $S$ be any infinite set and endow $S$ with the cofinite topology.  Note that if $f:S\to X$ is a continuous map from $S$ to a $T_1$ space with $|X|<|S|$, then $f$ must be constant: since $|X|<|S|$, there must be some $x\in X$ such that $f^{-1}(\{x\})$ is infinite, but then $f^{-1}(\{x\})$ must be all of $S$ since it must be closed.  It follows that if $X$ is an exemplary $T_1$ space, it must have at least $|S|$ points.  Since $S$ is arbitrary, this shows that no exemplary $T_1$ space exists.

For $T_2$ spaces, let $S$ be any infinite set with the discrete topology, let $S\cup\{\infty\}$ be its $1$-point compactification, and consider the space $X=S\times (S\cup\{\infty\})\cup\{z\}$, topologized as follows.  The subset $S\times (S\cup\{\infty\})$ is an open subset of $X$ and has the usual product topology.  A set $U\subseteq X$ containing $z$ is open iff for all but finitely many $s\in S$, $U$ contains all but finitely many points of $\{s\}\times S$.  It is easy to see this space $X$ is $T_2$.  Now suppose $Y$ is any $T_2$ (or even just $T_1$) space and $f:X\to Y$ is continuous.  Then for each $s\in S$, there is a $y_s\in Y$ such that $f(s,t)=y_s$ for all but $|Y|$ many $t\in S$ (otherwise, there would be two different values which $f(s,t)$ takes for infinitely many $t$, and then $f(s,\infty)$ would have to be equal to both of them).  Similarly, there is then a single $y\in Y$ such that $y_s=y$ for all but $|Y|$ many $s\in S$ (otherwise two values of $y_s$ would occur infinitely often, and then $f(z)$ would have to be equal to both of them).  We then have $f(z)=y$ and $f(s,\infty)=y$ for all but $|Y|$ many values of $s$.  It follows that if $U\subseteq Y$ is any open set such that $z\in f^{-1}(U)$, $(s,\infty)\in f^{-1}(U)$ for all but $|Y|$ many values of $s$.  If $|Y|<|S|$, this means that if $i:X\to \prod Y$ is any continuous injection from $X$ to a product of copies of $Y$, the set $i(X\setminus (S\times\{\infty\}))$ cannot be open in the subspace topology on $i(X)$ (since any neighborhood of $i(z)$ has to contain all but $|Y|$ many points of $S\times \{\infty\}$).  Since $X\setminus (S\times\{\infty\})$ is open in $X$, this means $Y$ cannot be exemplary for $X$.  Thus any exemplary $T_2$ space must have at least $|S|$ points; since $S$ was arbitrary, this means there is no exemplary $T_2$ space.